# How to Load a Data File into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a data file, vudbq.txt, with 247 lines.  The content of the data file is in JSON format.  But, the data file's extension is "txt".

I would like to load this data file into my local MongoDB as "one" record/document.

I did a search on the internet for MongoDB commands and I found:

```
mongoimport --db <db-name> --collection <coll-name> --type json  --jsonArray --file <file-name>.json
```

I have a number of questions:

1. Meanwhile, the MongoDB in my laptop has no data.  And the MongoDB directory is C:\mongodb\data\db.  After the data file is loaded, is the data file under C:\mongodb\data\db?  The MongoDB command shown above does not have an argument for me to specify the location of data storage.
2. I guess that I have to create a database name and a collection name.  Because my data file, vudbq.txt, is a record/document, should I change the extension of the file to json (i.e., vudbq.json)?

Comment: If it's just one document, you might just try copying the continents onto the clipboard and pasting it into the mongodb console. `db.mycollection.insert( <PASTE> )`.

Answer (score 1):

1. By default, [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) connects to a running instance of mongod on your machine (localhost:27017).  So, there's no need to specify a db path.  But, if you really want to, you can specify a `--dbpath` option to attach directly to local data files and insert the data without connecting to mongod.
2. There's no need to create a database or a collection before importing the data.  If the database/collection is not found, MongoDB creates it for you.  And there's no need to change the file extension.

From the documentation:

> **--dbpath**: Specifies the directory of the MongoDB data files. If used, the --dbpath option enables mongoimport to attach directly to local data files and insert the data without the mongod. To run with --dbpath, mongoimport needs to lock access to the data directory: as a result, no mongod can access the same path while the process runs.